qgis label straight line
For a map, I would like to align the labels on a single line.
I've changed the label co-ordinate settings to X = $x and Y to a fixed value.
The only problem is that I'm using LAMBERT coordinates and I have an (normal) offset (here to the right). I'd like them to be "right". I can't find the calculation to do. Or is there a simpler solution?


Sorry, I don't get the problem. Would getting the max y-value of your points and maybe adding like 2000 to that value work?

when you say you'd like them to be "right" do you mean parallel to the map edge?
